# C# how to wait for a webpage to finish loading before continuing in watin

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using watin  for automation and I'm stuck with a problem. I want to wait for a webpage to finish loading before continue how can I achieve this using watin currently I'm using thread.sleep() for achieve this. What will be the alternative for this and I also tried WaitForComplete() but still its not wait for finish loading the web page.

Comment: Commas would help understanding your problem. And maybe an example of the code you tried... We're not oracles.

Comment: @Optimus can you tell me in some more detail that how you are using Thread.Sleep() because I also tried to use this but I can't solve my problem which is same like you. You can see my question because I have some mysterious solution also that you might find useful.  Here is the link of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473103/waiting-for-page-to-be-fully-loaded-using-watin

Comment: @SaadQureshi see my answer below  Thread.Sleep() is not a good idea for this case because as you know Thread.Sleep(5000) will hold the process for 5 seconds even the process is ready in 2 seconds so using WaitUntilExists(60); will solve this problem because The 60 seeconds only means The maximum waiting time  and its will break if the element shows in 2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using `WaitUntilExists()` method. and I add a 60 seconds time out for the `WaitUntilExists()` because the default time out is 30 seconds and because of my  slow speed of internet I replaced it with 60 seconds like this  `browser.Div("div1").WaitUntilExists(60);`

Comment: I will sure try out this solution as I have nearly left my project.